# How to store response from sendRequest in Pre-request

Tags: javascript, postman

My code snippet in Pre-request is,

```
pm.sendRequest(
    {
    url: pm.environment.get("unused_num_url"),
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Authorization': 'Token acea677309814275e4a06826662a7cb576afe78a',
    },
    body: {
        "count": 1
    }, function (err, response) {
        var valu =  JSON.stringify(response);
        pm.globals.set("unusedNum", valu.val_numbers[0]);
        console.log("print here====================== "+valu);
    }
});
```

here, I am unable store the response to `valu` and `console.log` is also not printing anything. 
Any help how to do that?

Comment: Try it with `response.json()` and remove the `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Tried, but no luck. Same issue

Comment: The callback function is at wrong place, it's never inside the config object. Should be like `pm.sendRequest( {/*config*/} , function (err, response) { /*process result*/ });`

Comment: @Viney, This prints the log, but not the response instead it is printing request headers data. any suggestion

Comment: Use `var valu = response.json()` instead of `JSON.stringify`